# Code run but answer not correct ( python)

Tags: python

```
player_number=name_to_number(name)
player_number=int ()

# compute random guess for comp_number using random.randrange()
comp_number=random.randrange (0,4)

# compute difference of player_number and comp_number modulo five
rpsls_match = (player_number-comp_number)%5

 # use if/elif/else to determine winner
if rpsls_match == 1 or 2:
    rpsls_winner = 'Player wins!'
elif rpsls_match == 3 or 4:
    rpsls_winner = 'Computer wins!'
else:
    rpsls_winner = 'Player and computer tie!'

    #print "Player chooses " + name

   # convert comp_number to name using number_to_name
print 'Computer chooses ', number_to_name(comp_number),comp_number
print 'player chooses ' , name, player_number
return rpsls_winner
```

Code run correctly but i did not get answer what i want,, it give me answer like

```
Computer chooses  paper 2
player chooses  rock 0
Player wins!

Computer chooses  lizard 3
player chooses  paper 0
Player wins!

Computer chooses  spock 1
player chooses  scissors 0
Player wins!

Computer chooses  paper 2
player chooses  lizard 0
Player wins!

incorrect input
Computer chooses  lizard 3
player chooses  Spock 0
Player wins!
```

but I want like

```
Player chooses rock
Computer chooses scissors
Player wins!

Player chooses Spock
Computer chooses lizard
Computer wins!

Player chooses paper
Computer chooses lizard
Computer wins!

Player chooses lizard
Computer chooses scissors
Computer wins!

Player chooses scissors
Computer chooses Spock
Computer wins!
```

Comment: logical operator or is not proper used, you write like if 1 == 2 or 3 but if not it return 3 this is not logical statement which you want you should use 'in' operator for example like if var in (1,2)

Answer (score 3):

`rpsls_match == 1 or 2` should be

`rpsls_match in (1, 2)` or

`rpsls_match == 1 or rpsls_match == 2`.

Try evaluating `1 or 2` at the REPL. The answer is `1` because `or` returns the first non-false-evaluating operand.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
player_number=int ()
```

Will always set `player_number` to the default value for `int`, which is zero. You should remove that line to keep the value set in the previous line.